# how to use formatOnPaste correctly

Tags: visual-studio-code, monaco-editor

In [monaco-editor](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html?source=v0.39.0)

This is my config

```
var editor = monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById("container"), {
    value: "",
    language: "sql",

    lineNumbers: "off",
    roundedSelection: false,
    scrollBeyondLastLine: false,
    readOnly: false,
    theme: "vs-dark",
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: '800',
    formatOnPaste: true
});
```

But when I input this sql

```
select * from abc where abc.a="abc";select * from cba where cba.a="cba";
```

The sql is not formated.

It's same as which I input

The prop "formatOnPaste" is look like useless

So, how to use formatOnPaste correctly